# Why isn't my for loop working as I want it to?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying to make the loop terminate after either the computer or the player wins 5 games. I tried to do that with the for loop, but it isn't stopping at all. I tried to debug and figure it out but I am lost.
Can you please help me figure out where I  went wrong? Any suggestions to make the code more efficient would be very appreciated too.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissor {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    System.out.println("Lets play Rock, Paper, Scissors!");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int computerwins=0;
    int playerwins=0;


     Random random = new Random();
        for (int totalGame = 0; playerwins<=5 || computerwins<=5; ++totalGame){

            int gamenumber = totalGame + 1;
            System.out.print("Game " + gamenumber + ".  " + "Pick one! 1 = Rock, 2 = Paper, 3 = Scissor :   ");
            int input = scanner.nextInt();

            Random rand = new Random(); 
            int computerResponse = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;
            String compResponse = "something";
            switch (computerResponse) {
                case 1: compResponse = "Rock";
                    break;  
                case 2: compResponse = "Paper";
                    break;
                case 3: compResponse = "Scissor";
                    break;  }
            String you = "something";
            switch (input) {
                case 1: you = "Rock";
                    break;  
                case 2: you = "Paper";
                    break;
                case 3: you = "Scissor";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println("You: " + you + ", Computer: " + compResponse);

            if(input == computerResponse) {
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");  }
            else if (input == 1) {
                if (computerResponse == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You lose!");
                    ++computerwins; }
                else if (computerResponse == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You win!");
                    ++playerwins; } }
            else if (input == 2) {
                if (computerResponse == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Paper eats rock. You win!"); 
                    ++playerwins; }
                else if (computerResponse == 3) {
                    System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You lose!"); 
                    ++computerwins; }  }
            else if (input ==3) {
                if (computerResponse == 1) {
                    System.out.println("Rock crushes scissors. You lose!"); 
                    ++computerwins; }
                else if (computerResponse == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Scissor cuts paper. You win!"); 
                    ++playerwins; }  }

            System.out.println("Score Now: You = " + playerwins + ", Computer = " + computerwins );
            System.out.println("   "); }
        if (playerwins == computerwins) {
            System.out.println("Aww! It's a tie."); }
        if (playerwins < computerwins) {
            System.out.println("Aww! You lost!"); }
        if (playerwins > computerwins) {
            System.out.println("Yay! You won!");} 
        }   }
```

Thank you!!

Comment: You want `&&` instead of `||` in your loop condition.  Otherwise it will keep going till BOTH players have 6 wins.  Also, I think you want `<` instead of `<=`.  So `playerwins < 5 && computerwins < 5`

Comment: Your condition `playerwins<=5 || computerwins<=5` will only be false once *both* sides have more than 5 wins. If you want it to be either-or, change it to `playerwins<=5 && computerwins<=5`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Do you know a duplicate question which covers that? Since these kind of question appear quite often, it would be nicer to close them as a dupe instead of answering that over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop termination condition

```
playerwins<=5 || computerwins<=5
```

This continues as long as EITHER condition is true.  You want to change it to `&&` to continue until one condition becomes false.